# Cannot delete sqlite row using a contextual menu and listview in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a listview with a custom array adapter.
For my listview I setup a longitemclick for deletion.
By long press I display action menu with delete command as the following:

```
if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete)
{
 SparseBooleanArray selected = teamarrayadapter.getSelectedIds();
 short size = (short)selected.size();

 boolean number = mHelper.deleteTeam(new_id);
   for (byte I = 0; I<size; I++){
      if (selected.valueAt(I)) {
      String selectedItem = teamarrayadapter.getItem(selected.keyAt(I));
      teamarrayadapter.remove(selectedItem);
      }
   }
   // Close CAB (Contextual Action Bar)
   mode.finish();
   return true;
    }

 return false;
```

But it only deletes the list Item and not the data item which I delete with

```
public boolean deleteTeam (int teamId){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("teams", "teams_id = ? ", new String[]{Integer.toString(teamId)})>0;
}
```

how I can fix this?

Comment: You don't appear to be calling the `deleteTeam` method. Or is your issue how to call it or perhaps how to get the teams_id to then call `deleteTeam`? Or are you expecting the listView to propogate the deletion (which I believe is not something that a listview does).

Comment: I am calling it and return a boolean but its getting always false boolean number = mHelper.deleteTeam(new_id);

Comment: @MikeT I think the issue is that he has to call the deleteTeam method (which he does with `boolean number = mHelper.deleteTeam(new_id);`) But he feels like he shouldn't have to. I think he wants removing the item from the listView to be enough to accomplish what he wants.

Comment: No I want to remove the row from database as well

Comment: @Cfriend is the problem that when you call deleteTeam it is failing to remove the item from the database?

Comment: Yes! the id is correct, the where clause corresponds to a field, the name of table is correct, what does it wants!!!?

Comment: You could try using `db.execSQL(sqlstring)` e.g. `String sqlstr = " DELETE FROM  teams WHERE teams_id = " + Integer.toString(teamId) + " ;";
        db.execSQL(sqlstr);`

Comment: nothing still the same..